# Get variable from class to another class

Tags: java, class, oop, variables, getter-setter

I'm having trouble getting the variable of `class main` to another class `class members` ... Ive tried using getter-setter but it only return me a `null` value, how can i fix it? here are my codes:

Main.java

```
public class Main extends JFrame{

 JTextField txt = new JTextField(10);
 String value;

    Main(){

        getContentPane().add(txt);


        this.value = txt.getText(); 

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(300,200);
        setVisible(true);

    }//constructor of main


    public String getValue(){

        return this.value;

    }//getValue

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Main();
    }//psvm

}//class main
```

Members.java

```
public class Members extends JFrame{

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("");

    Main main = new Main();

    Members(){

        getContentPane().add(lbl);

        main.setVisible(false);

        lbl.setText(main.getValue());

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(300,200);
        setVisible(true);

    }//constructor of main

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Members();
    }//psvm

}//class members
```

Comment: Why do you have two `main()` methods?

Comment: because its just the simplified codes of my system..

Comment: I see txt being initialised, but nowhere do I see it's text property set. e.g. txt.settext(somestring);

Comment: i already tried it but didn't either..

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, you will get null value because value is being set in constructor

```
this.value = txt.getText();
```

Make sure that, you update the this.value whenever you update the textfield

```
JTextField txt = new JTextField(10);
```

Better way to addListener to txt

```
txt.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
     public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    //update value
   }});
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the code of your `Members`-class** there are **two members named `main`** which are ***one `Main`-class object*** and ***a `main()`-method***.

According to the principle of **OOP** a class cannot have more than one member with a single name **except in method overloading**.

Change the name of the `Main`-class object from `main` to `main1` or something else. Hope this will solve your problem.

Use the following code snippet-

```
public class Members extends JFrame{

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("");

    Main main1 = new Main();

    Members(){

        getContentPane().add(lbl);

        main1.setVisible(false);

        lbl.setText(main1.getValue());

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(300,200);
        setVisible(true);

    }//constructor of main

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Members();
    }//psvm

}//class members
```

Comment: still getting a null value.. =[

Comment: @PhantomKid you should cross-check other classes running in background. The modified code should run properly.